# read printf format from a bash var

Tags: bash, printf

I have a bash script I'm happy with::

```
$ printf '  Number of xml files: %s\n' `find . -name '*.xml' | wc -l`
42
$
```

then the message became longer:

```
$ printf '  Very long message here about number of xml files: %s\n' `find . -name '*.xml' | wc -l`
42
$
```

So I try to put it in a MSG var to stay at 80cols::

```
$ MSG='  Number of xml files after zip-zip extraction: %s\n'
$ printf $MSG `find xml_out -name '*.xml' | wc -l`
```

with no success::

```
$ printf $MSG `find xml_out -name '*.xml' | wc -l`
Number$
$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to put it inside double quotation

```
printf "$MSG"  `ls | wc -l`
```

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this way:

```
msg='  Number of xml files after zip-zip extraction: %s\n'
printf "$msg" "$(find xml_out -name '*.xml' -exec printf '.' \; | wc -c)"
```

- `msg` should be quoted in `printf` command.
- Avoiding pipeline with `wc -l` to address issues when filename may contain newlines, spaces or wildcard characters.
- Avoid all uppercase variables in shell.